# SHELLOPTS Defaults?

Tags: linux, bash, debian

Using Debian 5.0 (Lenny)...I can't find where SHELLOPTS is being set by default.  I've checked:

- ~/.bashrc
- ~/.profile
- ~/.bash_profile (doesn't exist)
- /etc/bash.bashrc
- /etc/profile

... nowhere to be found.  The issue is I want to change `emacs` to `vim` in editor style field.  Anyone know where I can find/set this?

Comment: Have you tried 'export EDITOR=vim' in .bashrc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It has some default settings. Just add:

```
set -o vi
```

to your `~/.bashrc` file.